# tap events with openlayers and mobiles dont work

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, openlayers

I use openlayers 2.13 and a vector layer from geoserver 2.1.3.

I dynamically create points in the vector layer with JS. If I tap my finger on a point, does not get "clicked" in smarthphones and tablets.

I use `<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>`. Is this enough? Should I use `OpenLayers.mobile.js` ?

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use the mobile build of the OpenLayers API script. This build contains a subset of the OpenLayers functions. OpenLayers 2.13 works well with all mobile browsers. However, I experienced that point selection can be a bit finicky on some devices. Can you confirm that the selection works as expected with a mouse input device? Is your OpenLayers application publicly accessible? If possible can you create a jsFiddle with the select control which is not working on the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific events for smartphones. They are touchstart, touchmove and touchend

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html

Hope it helps